# Highlight differences in row data of HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this HTML table in which:

- 1st row is a header of the table
- 3rd row shows erroneous data
- for every erroneous row, we have 1 row that shows correct data (2nd row).

I want to write a function in HTML/Javascript/Jquery to highlight cells with matching data between two rows. *We may have more than two rows of data.*

So basically, we will have to test rows in set of two i.e. 1st header row will be skipped. compare 2nd to 3rd, then test 4th to 5th, then 6t to 7th and so on.

In the example below, expected value in column 11 (column name: Required?) for Mr. John Popular, is "N", but excel report shows "Y".

For Mr. Bill Smith, i.e. in row 4 and 5 dates are different in "Future Exp Date" column and "date of service" column.

I want to highlight this difference.

```html
  
<table border="1" class="dataframe data">
      <thead>
        <tr style="text-align: right;">
          <th>Test</th>
          <th>first name</th>
          <th>last name</th>
          <th>person id</th>
          <th>contract id</th>
          <th>plan id</th>
          <th>authnumber</th>
          <th>request?</th>
          <th>window type</th>
          <th>date request </th>
          <th>Required?</th>
          <th>Solved?</th>
          <th>More attaintion?</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th>Future Exp Date</th>
          <th>Issue resolved?</th>
          <th>date of service</th>
          <th>date of exp</th>
          <th>date of system</th>
          <th>Receipt date</th>
          <th>TAT1</th>
          <th>DaysTAT1</th>
          <th>TAT2</th>
          <th>DaysTAT2</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Correct data</td>
          <td>John</td>
          <td>Popular</td>
          <td>759876</td>
          <td>J4856</td>
          <td>642</td>
          <td>837522</td>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>FO</td>
          <td>2019-01-14</td>
          <td>N</td>
          <td>N</td>
          <td>NA</td>
          <td>Approved</td>
          <td>2019-01-14</td>
          <td>NA</td>
          <td>NA</td>
          <td>NA</td>
          <td>2019-01-14</td>
          <td>NA</td>
          <td>0.0</td>
          <td>Y</td>
          <td>NA</td>
          <td>N</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Wrong Data</td>
          <td>John</td>
          <td>Popular</td>
          <td>759876</td>
          <td>J4856</td>
          <td>642</td>
          <td>837522</td>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>FO</td>
          <td>2019-01-14</td>
          <td>Y</td>
          <td>N</td>
          <td>NA</td>
          <td>Approved</td>
          <td>2019-01-14</td>
          <td>NA</td>
          <td>NA</td>
          <td>NA</td>
          <td>2019-01-14</td>
          <td>NA</td>
          <td>0.0</td>
          <td>Y</td>
          <td>NA</td>
          <td>N</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Correct data</td>
          <td>Bill</td>
          <td>Smith</td>
          <td>64963</td>
          <td>J6291</td>
          <td>642</td>
          <td>837522</td>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>FO</td>
          <td>2019-01-14</td>
          <td>N</td>
          <td>N</td>
          <td>NA</td>
          <td>Approved</td>
          <td>2019-01-17</td>
          <td>NA</td>
          <td>NA</td>
          <td>NA</td>
          <td>2019-01-18</td>
          <td>NA</td>
          <td>0.0</td>
          <td>Y</td>
          <td>NA</td>
          <td>N</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Wrong Data</td>
          <td>Bill</td>
          <td>Smith</td>
          <td>64963</td>
          <td>J6291</td>
          <td>642</td>
          <td>837522</td>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>FO</td>
          <td>2019-01-17</td>
          <td>N</td>
          <td>N</td>
          <td>NA</td>
          <td>Approved</td>
          <td>2019-01-18</td>
          <td>NA</td>
          <td>NA</td>
          <td>NA</td>
          <td>2019-01-14</td>
          <td>NA</td>
          <td>0.0</td>
          <td>Y</td>
          <td>NA</td>
          <td>N</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
    <button>Check constraints</button>
```

Comment: TBH, this question is a bit of a confusion:  *I have two rows* - there's 4 rows  *column 11* - there's 3 columns.   "*code should not highlight because data is not matching*" - but that's entirely what the code is for (or is it to highlight when they're the same?).  If you don't want to highlight anything... don't call `checkConstraints()`.   Can you clean up the question to make it clear what the results *should* be?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have create a copy of original code in https://jsfiddle.net/fkmz8swq/  . There are two rows and 1 header row. Both rows are identical. The only difference is in column 11.

Comment: It's not fantastic code, but it's also not a good SO question, so here's some comments:   `cell={}` should be `cachedValues={}` then it makes a bit more sense.   The .map() create an array just for easy of use/speed.  It then does a multi-dimension-array loop (classic `i`, `j` variables) and checks if the td text value is in the `cachedValues` - if not, adds it to the cache with a reference to the source cell(the td, see why cell is a bad name?).  If it is, calls highlight() using `arguments` which is a little unclear but converts the uncommon array call as `$([cell1, cell2])`

Comment: There's then a *second* check that compares the current column value with the the same column in the row *below* (which seems a little odd, but no real different to comparing with previous row)

Comment: The code uses `.toggleClass` where it should just use `.addClass` and `.removeClass` for clarity.

Comment: If you want to just check 2 rows to see if they match, remove all the `cell[]` code and just use the last `if(i<rows.length...` bit.   If you want to check a whole column, then I'd suggest refactoring it (rewriting it) so it works more like that last `if` but for the whole column.  It's not really clear what you're asking other than "help me understand"

Comment: Example: https://jsfiddle.net/cvrkwmso/ showing that the first part `if(cell[rows...` checks for existing values anywhere, not just on the next row (and seems a bit useless IMO - not being able to enter "N" into multiple bool fields???)

Comment: I guess the original example won't work with the HTML I have created. Thanks for the answer. I will try to write a new function to highlight matching cells of the HTML table that I have created.

Comment: You could try to explain what you're *trying* to do with the code.  At the moment you've just said "update so it doesn't highlight differences" - which is the same as not running the code at all.  So if we know what you wanted to do, you might get some help.  "highlight matching cells" - in what way should they match?  By column?  Across all cells?

Comment: I have created a flask appliacation to compare data between excel and database. Finally, I have created a table which shows data from database (correct data) in the first row. The second row shows erroneous data from excel (wrong data). I want to make it easy for the end user to see differences in database data and excel data by highlighting cells. Either I can highlight matching cells or erroneous cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a table which shows data from database (correct data) in the first row.
> Second row shows erroneous data from excel (wrong data).
>
> I want to make it easy for the end use to see differences in database data and excel data by highlighting cells

Taking the original code and 2 rows, remove the `cells` part as it checks along the row instead of down the column.  Can also remove looping rows as there's only two rows so it's a case of comparing `row[0][col]` with `row[1][col]`

With some other tweaks such as removing confusing `.toggleClass(class, true)` and a slight tweak to the class name / button caption to be clearer what they do, gives:

```js
function highlight(){    
    $(arguments).addClass('changed');
}
function checkConstraints(e){
    // reset style before re-checking
    $('td.changed').removeClass('changed');
    
    // get rows as an array of array
    var rows = $('tbody>tr').map(function(elem,i){
        return [$(this).children('td').toArray()];
    }).toArray();        
    
    // only 2 rows, so no need to loop them
    // start at j=1 to skip first column
    for(var j = 1; j < rows[0].length; j++){

      if (rows[0][j].innerText != rows[1][j].innerText) 
      {               
         highlight(rows[0][j],rows[1][j]);
      }            
    }        
}
$('button').click(checkConstraints);
```

```css
td {
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
table {
    border:1px solid black;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
td.changed {
    background:orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" class="dataframe data">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: left;">
      <th>Test</th>
      <th>first name</th>
      <th>last name</th>
      <th>person id</th>
      <th>contract id</th>
      <th>plan id</th>
      <th>authnumber</th>
      <th>date request </th>
      <th>Required?</th>
      <th>Solved?</th>
      <th>More attaintion?</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Correct data</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Popular</td>
      <td>759876</td>
      <td>J4856</td>
      <td>642</td>
      <td>837522</td>
      <td>2019-01-14</td>
      <td>N</td>
      <td>N</td>
      <td>NA</td>
      <td>Approved</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Wrong Data</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Wick</td>
      <td>759876</td>
      <td>J4856</td>
      <td>-642</td>
      <td>837522</td>
      <td>2019-01-14</td>
      <td>Y</td>
      <td>N</td>
      <td>NA</td>
      <td>Approved</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<button>Compare Rows</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! This code works! I will make some changes to make it runnable for multiple rows of data.